# How to dynamically populate selection box build parameter in Teamcity?

Tags: drop-down-menu, build, teamcity

In Teamcity, you can use a selection-box (i.e. a drop-down menu) as a build parameter. You can specify a list of values to be populated into the selection box. When a build is triggered, the user is asked to select the required value from the selection box.

I'd like these values to be populated dynamically. Specifically, I'd like to get a list of Maven release version from our Artifactory.

How can I tell Teamcity to dynamically populate the selection box?

Answer (score 3):

You can use my [plugin](https://github.com/grundic/teamcity-web-parameters) `teamcity-web-parameters` for that:

> Web-parameters is plugin for JetBrains Teamcity server, that extends
>   default dropdown box with parameters populated from web service. With
>   this plugin you can make your builds more flexible, as your parameters
>   would be populated on fly. For example, you can fetch options from
>
> - database query
> - VCS listing (folder, tag)
> - LDAP

Comment: Is there an example showing how to do it? Like using public rest API to populate web select dropdown?